# Intrusive ads on Google Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've been using an Android phone for 4 years (Nexus 5, LG G3, LG G4) and I recently swap to an iPhone.

Yesterday, a friend tweeted 2 photos of an ad when he was trying to read an article about a keyboard:

[image: intrusive ad]
"you've been selected by Amazon (...) in order win a Carte Cadeau Amazon of 1500€" (mistakes and missing words are intentional in order to translate in the best way)

[image: intrusive ad 2] "you have 2 minutes to answer blablabla"

Then, I remembered that I had that kind of ad when I was using Android with Google Chrome on mutiple websites. I've never get this on Google Chrome Desktop neither on Safari iOS.

I didn't find anything on internet about that and I think this is an Android problem, does someone have it too? Do you know what is the problem (is it an adware)? Do you have a solution?

Comment: Where did he read that article? It's probably that site 'feature', I get ads like this on particular sites not everywhere. It shows on android because android devices are targeted to see this on desktop you would see different thing if it's even shown for desktop.

Comment: The article was on a french PC hardware website and they told us on twitter that it didn't come from them. But it's not the only website where it happened to me

Comment: Try cleaning cache and data for chrome and visit site again to see if it happens. They probably lied

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје The problem is that it doesn't happen everytime. This might appear two times in a row as it might not appear for a week

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is adware. You should delete all settings in chrome, and including cache, cookies, history, etc. These kinds of spam happen when you think you are clicking something, but an invisible link is clicked instead, leading you to popup sites. Be careful about what sites you visit and what you click.

Comment: Good point but deleting history/data won't help since this invisible links will continue existing on those sites.

Comment: I thought about adware but MalwareByte/Kaspersky for Android didn't found anything. Also, this kind of spam load themselves even when you don't click anywhere, just when you load a website sometimes

Comment: You can install firefox, and install uBlock Origin extension for mobile to disable a lot of ads

Answer (score 0):

You should install an adblocker app, as AdAway ([link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.adaway/), very effective to block and prevent ads. Requirement : rooted device.